# ASP.NET Custom Validators - Page.Validate("groupName") not firing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, customvalidator

I have a custom validator in which the script validating the control is client-side JavaScript.

In my VB code behind for the website I call `Page.Validate("groupName")` but my validation script is not fired at all. I placed a break point in my JavaScript, but it's not even touching my validation script. While when I use the same function on non-custom validators it works.

I am thinking that it is impossibly to call my client-side validation script in my VB behind code via `Page.Validate("groupName")`. Do I absolutely need a server-side validation function?

Here's a bit of code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidateTxt" runat="server" 
     ClientValidationFunction="validateTxt" 
     ControlToValidate="txtBox" 
     Display="Dynamic"
     ValidationGroup="group1">
</asp:CustomValidator>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    function validateFinHeight(source, arguments)
    {
         if(arguments.Value % 2 == 0 ){
            arguments.IsValid = true;
         }             
    }
 </script>
```

**VB Behind Code:**

```
Protected Sub cbo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbo.SelectedIndexChanged
    Page.Validate("group1")
End Sub
```

The `Page.Validate("group1")` is not calling my JavaScript function.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need server-side validation because a user can bypass your javascript checks and submit whatever they want to your form.  The only way to be sure is check on the server-side.

Comment: I am not worried about the users bypassing because this is a simple web application that will only be used by about 3-4 people at the company I work at. It's not going to be open to the public where people are going to be trying dirty stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.Validate` is used to validate at *Server* side. If you want to trigger the client side validation then call the function `Page_ClientValidate("group1")` from your JavaScript code.